# What is the best practice to switch between view controllers for iOS in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

What is the best practice to switch between `UIViewControllers` for iOS in `Objective-C`? Now I have a menu `UIViewController` and a game's main screen `UIViewController`. In the menu there's a "New game" `UIButton` which should switch to the game's main controller. I do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)newGameButtonClicked:(id)sender {
  ViewController *gameViewController =
  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameViewController"];
  [self presentViewController:gameViewController animated:NO completion:^{
      // ...
  }];
}
```

When player dies, other view controller should be showed and I do it in the similar way like this:

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController = 
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
[self presentViewController:menuViewController animated:NO completion:^{
 // ...
}];
```

Is it right or there is a better way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use segues. Connect a segue from one view controller to another view controller, given an storyboard identifier to it and call it by using performSegueWithIdentifier method.

Comment: @Suresh a segue on a Game? Are you nuts?

Comment: @JoelHernandez why not? Doesn't he already initialize his view controllers through a storyboard? This: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 is a great tutorial on storyboards that also covers UIViewController transitions with segues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to init an `UIViewController` from the `UIStoryboard` you can do it like in your example. I would just use a `UINavigationController` as parent `UIViewController` and push them to the `UINavigationController`.

```
NSString *strVC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [MenuViewController class]];
MenuViewController *menuViewController = 
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:strVC];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:menuViewController 
                                     animated:YES];
```

When using `segues` like @mehinger explained, use `[segue destinationViewController]`. But this is just needed if you want to set any variables to the `UIViewController` before pushing it.

Comment: Why do you prefer push instead of present? And why do I need to use segues if I want to set any variables? I think that I can do it manually even in case of push

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a Navigation Controller:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or if you just want to present a new view:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to present a new viewcontroller in the same storyboard,

In CurrentViewController.m,

import "YourViewController.h"

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or if you are using navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

To set identifier to a view controller, Open MainStoryBoard.storyboard. Select YourViewController View-> Utilities -> ShowIdentityInspector. There you can specify the identifier.

Comment: Why do you prefer to use presentViewController and pushViewController methods instead of segues?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score -1):

Segues are the way to do when switching between view controllers:

```
- (IBAction)newGameButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToGameViewController"];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if(segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToGameViewController") {
        GameViewController *gameViewController = [GameViewController new];
        //do any other preparation you would like 
    }
}
```

In your storyboard you can then drag a segue from one view controller to the other and indicate its identifier as "goToGameViewController".

Comment: Why do I need to create gameViewController as a local pointer manually? Is it required? Should I do anything else for switching between view controllers in this case?

Comment: Also I've got an error "No visible @interface for "MenuViewController" devlares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier'"

Comment: @mehinger You should not be initializing a new view controller in `prepareForSegue`. Instead, use `[segue destinationViewController]` to get the `GameViewController` that is being transitioned to.

Comment: @DrBeardface Ok, but why am I need it? What should I do then to show it for the user? Can you provide the full example, please?

Comment: @DrBeardface right, that does make sense. @FrozenHeart The point of using `[segue destinationViewController]` is that it allows you to set up the destination view controller if any is necessary. If you are just looking to move to a new view controller you can create the segue in storyboard and call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]`

Comment: @mehinger But why is the seques the better way than the presentViewController?

Comment: @FrozenHeart I wouldn't say it is objectively better, that is just my preferred method. If you are using storyboard, segues are simpler because you don't have to write as much code and deal with presentation conflicts. If you are doing things programmatically, and your method works for you, there is no reason to switch over to segues.

Comment: @mehinger What type of segues should I create in my case? Push for button action and custom otherwise?

Comment: @FrozenHeart a push segue is used with a navigation controller. You are "pushing" the view controller on the "stack" of view controllers. I believe in your case you should use a modal segue.

Comment: @mehinger I think that I can use push and modal segues only in case of visual elements like buttons, am I right? But I want to show one view controller by logic conditions, not the user interactions (like timer expired). What type of segues should I use in this case?